# How to prevent an ESXi VM from syncing the time zone setting from a VMware Horizon client PC

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware-esxi, group-policy, vmware-horizon-view

I have some VMs running on ESXi, and users connecting via Horizon. I have a "Global Time Policy" GPO which is working correctly, but when users connect to their VMs via Horizon from another time zone, their local PC's time zone is redirecting to the VM. How do we avoid this situation?

Horizon: 7.9.0
ESXI: 5.5
Windows 10 1909

Answer (score 1):

Disable this group policy:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection > Allow time zone redirection
```

However, by default, [Timezone redirection is not enabled.](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.TerminalServer-Server::TS_TIME_ZONE)

Comment: Already did this, the problem not appears using RDP, only redirecting if connect by Horizon client.

Comment: @MichaelSmith did you try to set this in the View RDSH GPO ? https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-6/6.0/com.vmware.horizon-view.desktops.doc/GUID-443F9F6D-C9CB-4CD9-A783-7CC5243FBD51.html

Comment: We never used this before, and actually don't have this key in GPO. One strange thing, if i connecting using RDP, timezone is not redirecting, but if i connecting by RDP (protocol) using Horizon client, timezone redirecting. Looks like all issue is with Horizon, but i dont understand what.

Comment: @MichaelSmith you should use the GPO Bundle provided by VMWare, I'm not a VMWare customer so I can't download them, but you should be able to. They have specific GPO settings for Horizon.

Comment: This GPO Bundle as i understand using when need to "enable" redirection. you think it may help to disable?